# D3 combining selection with zoom/pan

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to implement tree node selection alongside with zoom/pan.
Considering that zoom/pan would conflict with selecting nodes with mouse (drag) I
implemented as two separate listeners between which I can switch using CTRL
keyboard button. Like this:

```
function toggleSelectZoom() {
    if (useZoom) {
        useZoom = false;
        zoomListener.on("zoom", null);
        container.classed("select", true)
            .on("mousedown.select", startNodeSelection)
            .on("mousemove.select", nodeSelection)
            .on("mouseup.select", endNodeSelection);
    } else {
        useZoom = true;
        container.classed("select", false)
            .on("mousedown.select", null)
            .on("mousemove.select", null)
            .on("mouseup.select", null);
        zoomListener.on("zoom", zoom);
    }
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) { if (e.ctrlKey) { toggleSelectZoom(); }};
```

But there is a problem: when switching to zoom/pan mode after
drawing a selection frame in selection mode, the tree (when starting to pan) jumps to a position where it
would be after the same manipulations in zoom/pan mode.
Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/PSVW6/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the zoom behaviour will still update its internal state, even if you're not acting on it. To solve, you have basically two options.

- Reset the internal state of the zoom behaviour if not handling the event this way. This would require you to keep track of the zoom/translate state yourself.
- Attach the zoom behaviour not to the entire SVG, but only to the elements themselves. This way, you would only be able to zoom/pan when the cursor is over an element and select elsewhere. This would eliminate the need for your switching logic in the handler, as the two sets of events would be separate.

It depends on your particular application which one of these solutions is more suitable.

Comment: How can I reset zoom behavior internal state without changing current translate/scale properties? Second option does not fit my needs because I need to be able to drag the nodes.

Comment: You would have to set `zoom.translate()` and `zoom.scale()`.